# Надзор без постоянного присмотра

Tags: семантика

Если в деревне или маленьком городе нет полиции и граждане сами наказывают преступников, можно ли употреблять понятие "надзор"? В таком случае никто не следит за порядком до совершения бесчинства, а только народ, отдельные лица "сбегаются" на место преступления.

Answer (score 1):

Не очень понятна ситуация, любая деревня находится в ведении какого-либо отделения полиции, может быть, участковый находится в соседней деревне или в близлежащем городе, но надзор всегда оформляется официально и кто-то из сотрудников полиции (в том числе сотрудники ППС) обязан навещать поднадзорного и ответствен за его поведение. Это всё равно надзор, если есть решение суда и там прописаны ограничения (нахождение вне дома с 22.00 до 6.00, запрет на посещение массовых мероприятий и т.д.), а вот если суд не определил надзор, то его и нет.

Почему за **Вашим** поднадзорным нет присмотра - это другой вопрос, это нарушение,  о котором Вы можете заявить.

Comment: Можно ли назвать "надзором" патруль? Т. е. когда поднадзорный ещё не определен.

Comment: Что значит "не определён?" Кто будет за ним надзирать? Впервые слышу о таком, суд пересылает определение в полицию, а та обычно закрепляет участкового. Сколько-то раз в неделю приезжают сотрудники ППС по заявке главного у участковых. Патруль просто так не останавливает, а если патрульные увидели поднадзорного после 22.00 на улице и знают его в лицо, они обязаны его остановить, списки поднадзорных у них есть.

Comment: Я имею в виду, например, Древнюю Грецию. Такое общественное устройство поселения, при котором преступники выявляются по своей приступной деятельности, на них сбегаются жители и их соразмерно наказывают. Нет периода, в который решается судьба преступника или происходит слежение за ним. Можно ли назвать надзором такой тип выявления преступников? То есть как бы употреблять это понятие в значении "патруль" — внимательность к бесчинствам.

Comment: Патруль - это всё-таки мобильная группа, а в Древней Греции был настоящий полицейский надзор, только он так не назывался. И были люди, сами вызывающиеся на отслеживание преступлений и их арест. https://cyberleninka.ru/article/n/organizatsiya-politseyskoy-sluzhby-v-drevnegrecheskih-polisah/viewer

Comment: Я ищу слово, синонимичное слову "внимательность", понятию "внимательность, осмотрительность граждан". И проверяю на корректность сочетания "Гражданский надзор" или "Гражданский патруль"

Comment: Может, бдительность?